# Magento 1.9 checkout stuck on shipping methods

Tags: shipping, onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0

I am having a problem with Magento 1.9 one page checkout- it gets stuck on shipping options. The shipping is set up as flat.
When trying to checkout it gets stuck on shipping methods- no error just not going further.
I have opened the console and got the error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

the log says this

> 2015-01-06T11:17:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: curl_setopt():
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set
>   in /home/pmtesten/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>   on line 510 2015-01-06T11:17:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: curl_setopt():
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set
>   in /home/pmtesten/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>   on line 510 2015-01-06T11:17:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: curl_setopt():
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set
>   in /home/pmtesten/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>   on line 510 2015-01-06T11:17:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: curl_setopt():
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set
>   in /home/pmtesten/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>   on line 510 2015-01-06T11:17:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: curl_setopt():
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set
>   in /home/pmtesten/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>   on line 510 2015-01-06T11:25:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT:
>   [0]
>   /home/pmtesten/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
>   [1]
>   /home/pmtesten/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
>   [2]
>   /home/pmtesten/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
>   [3]
>   /home/pmtesten/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
>   [4]
>   /home/pmtesten/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
>   [5] /home/pmtesten/public_html/app/Mage.php:684 [6]
>   /home/pmtesten/public_html/index.php:87

Answer (score 7):

change

```
<fieldset>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

to

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @deeps, the file is located here: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml` line `37` or there abouts. But you should not edit that file directly but copy into your theme folder.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely a shipper module is causing an exception that is happening in the backend.

Check your `var/log/` if none are present ensure you have logging enabled in the admin.

System > Config > System > Developer > Logging.

The error is a false positive:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca

Comment: My case, shipping cost calculation working on my cart page, but in my checkout page the shipping method not working, in cart page all shipping methods workings and displaying shipping cost, but the checkout page there no one shipping methods will display in my Magento Multi-store, help @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/216132/57334

Answer (score 0):

find
"?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') "
 above it there should be

"fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load>"

not just "fieldset>"